# Java Struts2 checkbox using s:iterator ognl.Noconversionpossible issue

Tags: java, struts2, iterator, ognl

I have list.add(int,String) in action class. I am getting this list in my jsp page as

```
<s:iterator value="list" var="emc" status="status">
  <s:checkbox name="selectedCoverage" fieldValue="%{#emc.dataId}" />
  <s:label value="%{#emc.PersonName}" />
</s:iterator>
```

Now I have three checkboxes, User did not selected any checkbox and hit submit which should throw validation errors. I have getters and setters for this check box in action class.

When I debug the code and see the value of selectedCoverage it is displaying me ognl.NoConversionPossibe instead of null. What is the issue and where am I going wrong?

Comment: Show us the action, and the validation...

Comment: I just have getters and setters like 'getSelectedCoverage()' and when I point my cursor on it in debug mode. I see ognl.noconversionpossible